# Bash script always returns 0 even with explicit exit 1

Tags: windows, bash, mercurial, exit-code, pre-commit-hook

**Problem:** I am trying to create an hg pre-commit hook. The commit always succeeds even if the only thing in the bash script invoked by the hook is "exit 1".

**What I've Tried:**

-Wrote a bash script that only had "exit 1" in it. (This still let the commit proceed. I would expect the commit to be aborted.)

-Put a pause in the bash script to verify it was being executed. (It was being executed)

-Set precommit directly equal to "exit 1" in the hgrc file. This successfully aborted the commit so I knew hooks were working.

-Wrote a python script that returned non-zero and that stopped the commit from happening. This verified that hooks were working with python scripts.

-Called my bash script from my python script and printed out the return value of the bash script in python. This always printed zero which tells me my bash script is not working correctly.

**Bash Example:**
hgrc file:

```
[hooks]
precommit = pre-commit.sh
```

pre-commit.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 1
```

**Python Example:**
hgrc file:

```
[hooks]
precommit = pre_commit.py
```

pre_commit.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

# I would expect this to print 1 since pre-commit.sh explicitly exits 1
# However this always prints 0
print os.system("pre-commit.sh")

# This is working fine. It succesfully aborts the commit
sys.exit(1)
```

I just want to reiterate that this has nothing to do with python. I only used python to check the value of my bash script. The problem is my bash script always returns 0 and I need it to return non-zero in order to abort a commit.
I have a feeling this is due to me running windows. I have git hooks working, but I believe that is because git bash interprets the script. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you delete pre-commit.sh?

Comment: "pre-commit.sh is not recoginized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. abort: precommit hook exited with status 1"

Comment: It appears exit status 1 works... so is that in general what you're looking for?

Comment: I just don't know why the exit 1 from the bash script isn't getting passed along to the hook.

Comment: Because there's no error executing pre-commit.sh it returns status 0... (successful). If you're trying to return an error there usually needs to be one (like when you deleted it).

Comment: What did calling your script from python look like exactly? If `cmd.exe` is running the hook instead of `sh`/`bash` that might act very differently than `sh`/`bash` on exit codes.

Comment: @I'L'I According to Mercurial: The Definitive Guide: "Failure is indicated with a non-zero exit status from an external hook, or an in-process hook returning boolean “true”." I thought I was indicating failure by putting that exit 1 in the script. Is this a false assumption?

Comment: @EtanReisner It looked like this: print os.system("pre-commit.sh") sys.exit("Tests Failed").

Comment: @RichardHammond: What happens if you do `sys.exit(1)`?

Comment: sys.exit(1) will abort the commit as expected

Comment: @I'L'I Sorry but I guess I don't see how that helps me? I only used python as a sanity check to see if I could make commits fail at all and to print out the value of my bash script. Python seems to be working fine. I just want to get my bash script working.

Comment: "will abort the commit as expected" — I'm not exactly following what the problem is if you're now getting the "expected" behavior.

Comment: The problem is no matter what I try, I cannot get a bash script to abort the commit. The python script aborts the commit as expected. I have to use bash because it invokes other things like rake that python doesn't know about.

Comment: I would suggest posting all the relevant information... (eg. how you called python script, how you called the bash script from the python script, etc.) - really the more info you include the easier to narrow things down. Also show everything you actually did try... from your question it seems like you tried two things and that's it.

Comment: Is `sys.exit(1)` works and `sys.exit("Test Failed")` doesn't work to end the hook then that sounds like something is up with `sys.exit` when given a string. Also `print os.system("pre-commit.sh") sys.exit("Tests Failed")` should **always** fail the commit since the exit code from `pre-commit.sh` is ignored and python should always be exiting with `1`. That said internal python hooks are supposed to `return True` for failure.

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry for the confusion. sys.exit with text works correctly for me. I only used python to debug my bash script. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Does `print os.system("pre-commit.sh")` work correctly from the python interpreter directly? Does `print os.system("/bin/sh pre-commit.sh")` work differently? Are you sure you have the path to the script correct in the `os.system` call? (That should produce a different error if you don't but let's just check everything.

Comment: I believe `print os.system("pre-commit.sh")` is working correctly. I can see the pre-commit.sh script executing. `print os.system("/bin/sh pre-commit.sh")` gave the error "The system cannot find the path specified" and printed out '1'.

Comment: `os.system("pre-commit.sh")` works? How does Windows know what to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "pre-commit.sh" on windows and expect it to work without telling Windows what to do with this.

You can use a bat-file like this (because the OS knows what to do with it!):

```
C:\temp>echo @echo test>pre-commit.bat
C:\temp>echo @exit 1 1>>pre-commit.bat
C:\temp>python -c "import os,sys;sys.exit(os.system('pre-commit.bat'))"
test
C:\temp>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```